# Can anyone solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve this but no luck. It did not work out also with Mathematica using `DSolve`.

The equation: $y'(x)^{1/N} + x\ \frac{d}{dx} (y'(x)^{1/N}) - (y/x)^{1/N} = - A P/(2 \pi)$

BCs: $y(0)= 0$ and $y'(0) = 0$

Thank you.

Comment: $N,A,P$ are constants? If so then this is not a PDE, but a nonlinear ODE.

Comment: What is the context for this equation? Where does it come from?